# Your APK should only require hardware features that are usually available on tablets

Tags: android, android-permissions

Below is what our application manifest looks like, and its published in playstore, and we are getting this message under optimization tips

**"Your APK should only require hardware features that are usually available on tablets."**

Also we have verified that our app is not available in tablets which do not have phone facility. So how can we make it available for all device.Is it because of "MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" Permission? If yes how we can solve this?

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

Be careful, from now on `getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)` may return null and you need to handle this case gracefully.

Comment: Means we can remove any permissions ? or just adding this feature will do solve the problem?

Comment: @unitedartinc If you want to use the feature you have to keep the permission. If you don't necessarily need to use the feature you add the line i mentioned and deal with the cases when there's no TelephonyManager in your code.